# Is $\int_{E_k}f\underset{k\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }\int_E f$

Tags: measure-theory

If $E_k$ is mesurable such that $E_k\to E$ with $E$ measurable and if $f$ integrable can I do (by theorem convergence dominated)
$$\int_{E_k}f\underset{k\to\infty }{\longrightarrow }\int_E f\ \ ?$$

I would say yes because
$$\int_{E_k}f=\int f\chi_{E_k}$$
and $|f\chi_{E_k}|\leq |f|$, therefore by theorem convergence dominated,
$$\lim_{k\to\infty }
\int_{E_k}f=\int \lim_{k\to\infty }f\chi_{E_k}=\int f\chi_E=\int_E f.$$

Do you think it's right ?

Comment: Yes, it's right.

Comment: Tks :-) An other small question, if $\{E_k\}_{k\in\Bbb N}$ is a collection of measurable such that $E_k\to E$, is $E$ necessarily measurable ?

Comment: @idm: What is your definition of $E_k \to E$? Depending on that, your question should answer itself. Also, your proof uses (more or less) that $\chi_{E_k} \to \chi_E$. Hence, you should show that this is implied by your definition of $E_k \to E$.

Comment: I interpreted your convergence as meaning $\chi_{E_k}$ converges pointwise to $\chi_E$. The pointwise limit, if it exists, of  a sequence of measurable functions is measurable.

Comment: @PhoemueX: the $\lim_{k\to\infty } E_k$ exists and I set $E$ the limit.

Comment: @idm: Ok, what is your definition of $\lim_{k \to \infty} E_k$?